# Error when trying to open url in python jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I am trying to open google website using python jupyter notebook but the error "SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier" occurs on line 5. As i am still relatively new to Python, there may be errors occurring on other lines too.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url = “https://www.google.com/"
try:
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
 print(“An error occured.”)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, ‘html.parser’)
print(soup)
```

[image]

output after changing to "

[image]

Comment: Python does not allow character `“` (or `”`). Use `"`.

Comment: @DYZ ah thanks, i have replaced all the “ and ‘ with ". But after that it does not take me to google tho. Instead it shows a whole chunk of codes as shown above. Why is this so?

Comment: This is a different question and should be posted separately. However, you _cannot_ google things like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing what it is supposed to print. 
using this line:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

you are getting BeautifulSoup object, which represents the document as a nested data structure. if you want more beautiful and structured output you can try

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

it will give you a formatted html like output
like this 
[image]